# Spinnaker AWS Provider not allowing create cluster

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Deployed Spinnaker in AWS to run a test in the same account. However unable to configure server groups. If I click create the task is queued with the account configured via hal on the CLI. Anyway to troubleshoot this, the logs are looking light.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you resolve this? please share you hal config

Answer (score 0):

Storage backend needs to be configured correctly.

https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/storage/

Comment: how come? i have S3 persistance enabled. This has to do with something else. I am running from a Debian Local install